# Custom loader is displayed before the beginning of output creation process n a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which if I give a name except of the default `consent.name`,give the password `makis` and press the `Get started`  an rmd output is generated.
As you will see while the report is being created a loading message is displayed. The issue is that this loading message is displayed before doing anything at all and this is confusing. How can this loading message be displayed only when the `Name` and `Password` inputs are correct and the `Get started actionButton()` is pushed? I believe that the loading message created with withLoader() should be moved from the `ui` to the `server` part of the code in order to follow the same logic as the rmarkdown `uiOutput()`.

the ex.rmd

```
---
title: "An example Knitr/R Markdown document"
output: pdf_document
---


{r chunk_name, include=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x, y)
```

and the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(knitr)
library(shinycustomloader)
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:25px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 1250px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("well", "Welcome")),

  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Welcome", tabName = "well", icon = icon("house"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("well",
                fluidRow(),
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  fluidRow(textInput("name", label = ("Name"), value = "consent.name")),
                  passwordInput("pwd", "Enter the Database browser password"),
                  withLoader(uiOutput('markdown'),type="html",loader = "loader1"),
                  actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%')
                  ))
       
      )
      
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    observeEvent(input$button,{
      if (input$name=="consent.name"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          output$markdown <- renderUI({
            HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('ex.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
          })
          
        }
        else{
          return(NULL)
        }
      }
    })
    
  }
  )
)
```